# How would I structure a single page application that takes an input, fetches data from the back end, then renders it to the front end with routers?

Tags: html, reactjs, django

Example: https://redditmetis.com/

### Issue

I've been having trouble trying to structure a recent SPA I started. Like the above example, I need to accept an input, make a few API calls in the back-end, manipulate the data then render it the front-end. I'm currently going for a Django + React stack, since I'm pretty familiar with them. I can't really imagine how this would look like from a surface view, I've worked with API's before but I can't wrap my head around how the client and the server would interact with each other to make it all connect.

### What I have so far

After looking into it, I think I need React Routers, similar to the example website provided. In my Django server, I plan on making separate API calls and running an algorithm to organize and sift through the received response, then pushing the product to the client. I'm still figuring out how to set that up, since most API calls are made on `componentdidmount` which only executes at the start of the DOM. This isn't much, but its a start.

If anyone has pointers on how to start, I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: This isn't a properly formatted question for stackoverflow and may be better suited for the Software Engineering stack exchange https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Each class object you make can have a componentdidmount method.

You can also use the fetch method within objects that update dynamically during state changes.